# How can I receive multipart/form-data in Spring MVC Controller?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, kotlin, multipartform-data

I need to implement a REST-Endpoint, that receives multipart/form-data
I use:

- Spring Boot
- Kotlin
- Spring MVC

A multipart form submit with the following parts:

deployment-name ----- text/plain 
enable-duplicate-filtering ----- text/plain 
deploy-changed-only ----- text/plain 
deployment-source ----- text/plain 
tenant-id ----- text/plain 
* ----- application/octet-stream

The Rest Controller looks so:

```
    @PostMapping("/data/deployment/create")
    fun uploadDmn(
            @RequestParam("deployment-name")
            deploymentName: String,
            @RequestParam("enable-duplicate-filtering")
            enableDuplicateFiltering: String?,
            @RequestParam("deploy-changed-only")
            deployChangedOnly: String,
            @RequestParam("deployment-source")
            deploymentSource: String,
            @RequestParam("tenant-id")
            tenantId: String,
            @RequestParam("data")
            data: MultipartFile
    ) {
        println(deploymentName)
        println(deployChangedOnly)
        println(deploymentSource)
        println(tenantId)
        println(data.toString())
    }
```

For all params that works, but for the last one that doesn't work.
I've tried to give a name "data", "*", "file" that doesn't work.

> Required request part 'data' is not present

The Controller doesn't see that file.

I've tried too to use Retrofit:

```
    @PostMapping("/data/deployment/create")
    @Multipart
    fun uploadDmn(
            @Part("data")
            data: MultipartFile
    ) {
        println(data.toString())
}
```

But that doesn't work too:

> Parameter specified as non-null is null

How can I work with that content type? multipart/form-data

Example of Request:

```
--28319d96a8c54b529aa9159ad75edef9
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="deployment-name"

aName
--28319d96a8c54b529aa9159ad75edef9
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="enable-duplicate-filtering"

true
--28319d96a8c54b529aa9159ad75edef9
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="deployment-source"

process application
--28319d96a8c54b529aa9159ad75edef9
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="data"; filename="test.bpmn"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bpmn2:definitions ...>
  <!-- BPMN 2.0 XML omitted -->
</bpmn2:definitions>
--28319d96a8c54b529aa9159ad75edef9--
```

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Have you set the `spring.servlet.multipart.enabled` to be `true`?

Comment: @LHCHIN no, but I've tried to do that in application.properties. Still the same problem: `Parameter specified as non-null is null`

Comment: You should add the multipart filter before the crsf one. https://stackoverflow.com/a/35405063/11951081

Answer (score 1):

I hope I can help you with that.  Try it.

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/putRequest",
        produces = { "application/json" }, 
        consumes = { "multipart/form-data" },
        method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public ResponseEntity<SuccessDto> requestPut(@Valid @RequestParam(value = "commit", required = false, defaultValue="false") Boolean commit, @Valid @RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Comment: I don't know why you have annotated 90% of the code with a Swagger, but the main part is here the annotation `@RequestPart`. Unfortunately that doesn't work too. The same problem "Required request part 'data' is not present". I think the problem is in the App that sends this request. The App is "Camunda Modeler".

Comment: "I think the problem is in the App that sends this request." I agree.  The code above expects a FormData object in the body with the key "file".  Of course I do not know in which form the client sends his request.  Maybe the key has to be adjusted.

Comment: Try to change @RequestPart("file") with @RequestPart("data").

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this I guess:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/source/upload/{sourceName}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public List<String> uploadSource(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile sourceFile,
            @PathVariable("sourceName") String sourceName) throws IOException {
        File outputFile = new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"), sourceFile.getOriginalFilename());
        sourceFile.transferTo(outputFile);
        <<your business logic>>
        Files.deleteIfExists(outputFile.toPath());
        return Arrays.asList(columns);

    }
```

Note that I have created a copy of the file in the temp-directory (via code) and am using the file there to implement my business logic