# How to add csrf token for immediate file upload for Spring Security 3.2?

Tags: jsf, file-upload, spring-security, csrf, richfaces

I have been trying to add CSRF token for file uploads in my Spring application having spring security 3.2. The [Spring Security CSRF documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.0.CI-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/csrf.html)  suggests we add `MultipartFilter` before the spring security filter so that temporary file upload becomes possible without spring security altogether (and hence without CSRF checking also). But wouldn't that be less secure?
Although, to have a working software atleast, I applied the above method but its not working. In error log it looks like the multipart filter is being triggered before the spring security filter, but still it IS going in the spring security filter and then to CSRF filter.
I am using `<rich:fileUpload>` with `immediateUpload="true"` to upload the file in the form.

May I get some help in applying this? It would be better if we can add the CSRF token itself instead of circumventing the security filter.

Comment: if you disable csrf altogther and tried the file upload, does it working? just to rule out any other authentication issues

Comment: Thanks for answering ;-) and Yes after removing the <csrf/> tag in application context xml the uploading worked.

Answer (score 2):

`MultipartFilter` does not stop the spring security filters from being invoked. But by putting it as the first filter in the filter chain, **when there is a csrf token available in body as a param**, it makes it possible for `csrf token filter` to extract the csrf token from body and verify it.

**Short answer**

You still neef to send csrf token but you can send it in body as a hidden param or in the url as a query param.

Note:

- I dont have knowledge about the ui component you use but in your previous get request, you should have received a `_csrf` token as hidden param and you should include it as part of the url or as a hidden param in the multipart request.
- If it is not clear, just to make a GET and POST request working without fileupload to understand the csrf flow

**Alternative: Skip the csrf only for file upload**

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {


        http.csrf()
                .requireCsrfProtectionMatcher(new CustomRequiresCsrfMatcher())
            .and()
            ......
    }

    private static final class CustomRequiresCsrfMatcher 
                                implements RequestMatcher {
        private final HashSet<String> allowedMethods = new HashSet<>(
                Arrays.asList("GET", "HEAD", "TRACE", "OPTIONS"));


        @Override
        public boolean matches(HttpServletRequest request) {
            String upload_url = "your file upload url";//update it
            
            return !this.allowedMethods.contains(request.getMethod()) &&
                     
                 !request.getRequestURL().toString().contains(upload_url);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thnaks for answering @Kavithakaran ;-). But one question I am still having, why do we need the MultipartFilter separately, I mean, other POST forms work perfectly with the csrf configuration as I have added the csrf token as hidden input in every form, its the upload request only which doesnt contain the csrf token, although the form it is part of does contain the csrf token input. how do I add the csrf token in the body of Upload request separately?

Comment: On a normal request, csrf token can be extracted by request.getParam by the csrf token filter. But in a multipart http request, it will not work. So someone (`MultipartHttpFilter`) sits in front of csrf filter and resolves the multipart request. Once it us done, csrf token filter can extract the csrf token. See the answer for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35392795/resolving-multipart-form-data-request-in-spring-filter

Comment: That really explains a lot, but it looks like I may have to implement my own CSRF Filter.

Comment: how are you sending the csrf token now for your upload? if you sending it but spring security is not understanding that, then it is easy to fix

Comment: because even if you implement your custom, you still need to send the csrf token in your upload

Comment: Alternatively you can skip the csrf for file upload only as above

Comment: The upload does not contain the csrf token, I am using <rich:fileUpload> to upload and its documentation does not give any information on how to add the CSRF token along with the upload request. https://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/rich_fileUpload.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216827/discussion-between-kavithakaran-kanapathippillai-and-jaideep-sagar).

Comment: @KavithakaranKanapathippillai What was the final conclusion to this chat discussion? The discussion link is gone / expired.