# Spring boot http request logger interrupts the controller

Tags: java, spring, api, http

I am using a custom logger to log all http request that enters the server, it worked fine until now but when I get a 'multipart/form-data' request, it fails and doesn't execute the function in the controller at all.

When I remove the logger class from the program it works, so I am sure the request handling is somewhat missing in the logger class.

LoggableDispatcherServlet.class

```
public class LoggableDispatcherServlet extends DispatcherServlet {

    private final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

    @Override
    protected void doDispatch(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        if (!(request instanceof ContentCachingRequestWrapper)) {
            request = new ContentCachingRequestWrapper(request);
        }
        if (!(response instanceof ContentCachingResponseWrapper)) {
            response = new ContentCachingResponseWrapper(response);
        }
        HandlerExecutionChain handler = getHandler(request);

        try {
             super.doDispatch(request, response);
        } finally {
            log(request, response, handler);
            updateResponse(response);
        }
    }

    private void log(HttpServletRequest requestToCache, HttpServletResponse responseToCache, HandlerExecutionChain handler) {
        LogMessage log = new LogMessage();
        log.setHttpStatus(responseToCache.getStatus());
        log.setHttpMethod(requestToCache.getMethod());
        log.setUrl(requestToCache.getRequestURI());
        log.setClientIp(requestToCache.getRemoteAddr());
        log.setJavaMethod(handler.toString());
        log.setResponse(getResponsePayload(responseToCache));
        logger.info(log);
    }

    private String getResponsePayload(HttpServletResponse response) {
        ContentCachingResponseWrapper wrapper = WebUtils.getNativeResponse(response, ContentCachingResponseWrapper.class);
        if (wrapper != null) {

            byte[] buf = wrapper.getContentAsByteArray();
            if (buf.length > 0) {
                int length = Math.min(buf.length, 5120);
                try {
                    return new String(buf, 0, length, wrapper.getCharacterEncoding());
                }
                catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
                }
            }
        }
        return "[unknown]";
    }

    private void updateResponse(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        ContentCachingResponseWrapper responseWrapper =
                WebUtils.getNativeResponse(response, ContentCachingResponseWrapper.class);
        responseWrapper.copyBodyToResponse();
    }

}
```

I can see that the failure is when I call

```
super.doDispatch(request, response);
```

I believe that it can only handle simple requests like application/json content but I guess that when the request is different it is unable to handle this.

I tried to implement some of the things mentioned in the answer here - [resolving-multipart-form-data-request-in-spring-filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35392795/resolving-multipart-form-data-request-in-spring-filter) - but I couldn't make it work.

Comment: Ditch your `LoggableDispatcherServlet` and write a `Filter` instead. Or even better use one of the Spring provided logging filters like the `CommonsRequestLoggingFilter` which does this already. Or at least just use a filter to wrap the request in the content caching types and use a HandlerInterceptor to write the logging.

Comment: I think it just logs the request, is there a way to log responses as well?

Comment: No it logs the request (was thrown of by the title of your question). Nonetheless the second part of the comment still holds.

Comment: Sounds a bit complicated but I will search it and try, if you can point me to: examples, docs, etc I would appreciate it!

Comment: Why complicated. Wrap the thing in your filter, do the logging in an interceptor. YOu already have the code. However, your question is a bit vague on what goes wrong/doesn't happen.

Comment: Ok I will try that and update if something goes wrong. Thank you!